# Promises.resovle vs new Promise

Tags: ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise, ecmascript-5

Lateley i see more short ways to use Promsies without need to Actually create new Promise ,

```
userBusiness.getAllFiles()
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    });

export namespace userBusiness {
    export async function getAllFiles() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                return resolve("files has arrvied");
            }, 5000)
        })
    }
}
```

This approach works, but I wanted to use a different approach with `Promise.resolve`

```
return setTimeout(() => {
    return Promise.resolve("files has arrvied");
}, 5000)})
```

This seems to return me an Object of `setTimeout` and not the input "files has arrived". Why? Using `Promise.resolve` still mimics the promise mechanism, doesn't it?

Comment: You can't `return` anything (useful) from a `setTimeout` callback. Doesn't matter whether it's a promise or not.

Answer (score 0):

> In the second case, `promise` is returned only when the callback is
>   called in the `setTimeout`. That is, the `getAllFiles` returns a
>   `setTimeout` object, not a `promise`.